# Slow delivery with Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

We are using the Gmail API to send emails to our users at the time of registration. Everything has been working fine, but lately (since about a month) some emails are taking some minutes to arrive.

There is no error or log, it is just slow. Pasting the headers of an email into https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/analyzeheader we can see that the email is delayed some minutes on a server from Google

[image: message-header analysis]

The Google Developers Portal links to this tag in stackoverflow for support, but we couldn't find more information about it.

How can we know why is this happening? and how can we prevent it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

-- UPDATE

We tested using SMTP with JavaMail directly to send the emails and the delivery times are back to normal